# Does Firefox support folder upload?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I enjoy folder upload in Google Drive, which works in Google Chrome.

Recently, I've [switched back](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/v0CxM5ur-PE[143-143]) to Firefox, and when I tried to upload a folder to Google Drive just now:

[image: Google lying about Firefox support of folder upload]

Is that true? Does Firefox in fact lack some Folder upload functionality that Chrome has? Or is this a generous wording of Google's decision not to implement the feature for Firefox?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Current Nightly (version 45) implements [Directory upload](https://wicg.github.io/directory-upload/proposal.html) specification. It can be enabled in `about:config` using key `dom.input.dirpicker`.

- [API introduction](https://jwatt.org/blog/2015/09/14/directory-picking-and-drag-and-drop)
- [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1188880)

Comment: I'll keep an eye on this- when at least the config option makes it into the stable release, I'll confirm and consider revising the correct answer on this.

Comment: This feature is enabled by default in Nightly (version 46).

Comment: I have just tried Firefox 46 stable on Google Drive, even manually added `dom.input.dirpicker` in about:config and restarted browser. I am still told folder upload is not supported.

Comment: That's right. The [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1188880) status is still "new" - the feature was not yet released and thus it is not yet available in Firefox release channel. If you want to try a demo, you can visit https://jwatt.org/tmp/directory.html using Firefox Nightly. In order for this to work with Google Drive, Google also needs to re-implement Drive upload mechanism to use Directory upload spec.

Comment: **This feature was removed** in Firefox 101 ([code](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/commit/c82b0711e1dede229b337bdb2625c10ed5c91261), [issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1760560)). Before that, it was available via an off-by-default `about:config` setting `dom.input.dirpicker`. 
It was made off-by-default in Firefox 50: ([code](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/commit/67f00dc15b), [issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1283053)).
Before, it was on-by-default only in Firefox Nightly.

Answer (score 7):

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=782233

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=876480

Unless folder uploading becomes a web standard I doubt whether Firefox will implement it.